# Analog DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I write pl/sql procedure in Oracle and suspect that it possible will run long enough I usually use `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE ('Some calculation', i||' records of '||total_count||' were processed')` in order to have ability to monitor calculation process.

Is there something similar in SQL Server to monitor calculation process through system views?

Comment: Please explain what that actually does for people not familiar with Oracle.

Comment: For example:
I opened some cursor and go though it processing somehow every record. I whant to know how many records were processed already.
This case I use counter variable (suppose i) and make increment it in each cicle i := i + 1
The value of this variable I want to see and for this I use system Oracle procedure DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE to "publish" counter value which I could see in system view.
Do I have such instrument in MS Sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view progress in a long running SQL job I normally just intersperse `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` messages.

```
RAISERROR ('Some calculation %i records of %i were processed',0,1,50,100) WITH NOWAIT;
```

These info messages can be retrieved and displayed by the executing application (printed in the messages tab of SSMS for example).

Sounds like the Oracle thing is a bit different. You can stuff arbitrary 128 byte messages in `CONTEXT-INFO`

```
DECLARE @Msg BINARY(128) = CAST('Some calculation 50 records of 100 were processed' AS BINARY(128))

SET CONTEXT_INFO @Msg
```

And then retrieve it as

```
SELECT CAST(context_info AS CHAR(128))
FROM   sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE  session_id = 55  /*Change as needed*/
```

Another possibility would be to fire a custom profiler event with [`EXEC sp_trace_generateevent`](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/testing-with-profiler-custom-events-and-database-snapshots) that you could then capture.

But probably easier to just add a logging table that your steps get inserted into (may need to query this with `NOLOCK` if your steps are running inside a transaction).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to pull every change of my counter into output log.
I want to monitor my calculation process through some system view or somehow "on demand"

Comment: @AlexZhulin - There isn't an exact analog of `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`. My answer give 4 different possibilities in lieu of that.

Comment: After you addition info about set context_info it seems useful for me. Thank you again.

Comment: Each query runs in a transaction anyways even if you don't explicitly set it up. Out of the entire post, sp_trace_generateevent is the closest equivalent to what OP requests.